# VBA Count Occurrence of Field X from Table A Record A within Table B and Insert Into Table A Record A Field Y

Tags: vba, ms-access, count

I have two tables.

For Example 
Table-A is a list of orders
Table-B is a list or Colors Options (up to around 1000 options)

Both tables are temp tables on the same form and recreated when a date range is adjusted or a different user is selected.

Would like to add a Field(aka, column) to the far end of Table-B that counts the instances of Table-b Field-A (lets call it color) in Table-A.

This would have to occur up to around 1000 times so I am not sure an array of color options built from Table-B is appropriate or a calculated column?

'Original Thoughts...

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim TD As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim i As Integer

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set TD = db.TableDefs("tblColor")

Set fld = TD.CreateField("NbrOrders", dbInteger)
fld.Expression = ColorCountCalc([Color])
TD.Fields.Append fld
```

This does not work as counting instances of an item from Table-B (tblColor) within a different table-A is more complex than what I was thinking.

Basically, Not sure this is the best approach or if maybe looping through Table-B and just doing a count and insert result is best, though afraid will bog everything down...

Is there a simply way to accomplish this count on tblA from tblB and insert into tblB?

Comment: You will typically use queries for such task. Modifying tables is a very bad idea.

Comment: There are both Temporary tables for viewing in one form. (Like a snapshot of progress made) This would not modify any true data stored in the db.

Comment: OK. But still, why not a query - seems much easier to me.

Comment: Table-B is a temp table built using the following
UserName= Left(Me.cboUser, Len(Me.cboUser) - 6)
sql = "INSERT INTO tblTempTableB SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE UserFieldName = '" & UserName & "'"
CurrentDb.Execute sql  Table-A is a temp table built using results from Table-B. The count is of times in table-A. So create Table-B, Create Table-A, add column to table-B  ........this can not be done in one query. I cant count values in A if I first need B to make A and the result is to be in B .....does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Table-B is a temp table built using the following 
UserName= Left(Me.cboUser, Len(Me.cboUser) - 6) 
sql = "INSERT INTO tblTempTableB SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE UserFieldName = '" & UserName & "'" CurrentDb.Execute sql

Table-A is a temp table built using results from Table-B.

Table-B rebuilt to add count column
    'Create new tblTempTableB table ***NEW***
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryMaketblB"
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        Forms!frmForm.Refresh

Is ridiculous but works.